# calling javascript function after angular routechange

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a javascript function inside a file i route into an ng-view in an Angular project. Is there a way to execute said function after the routing has finished? similar to JavaScript's window.onload?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: In the route, a component will get loaded so why not call the function in its lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a router event,
In your constructor,

```
    constructor(private router: Router) {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
         // call your function here
        }
      });
    }
```

Dont forget to import

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

This event is called only when the navigation is about to end.

```
**The sequence of router events is as follows,**
NavigationStart,
RouteConfigLoadStart,
RouteConfigLoadEnd,
RoutesRecognized,
GuardsCheckStart,
ChildActivationStart,
ActivationStart,
GuardsCheckEnd,
ResolveStart,
ResolveEnd,
ActivationEnd
ChildActivationEnd
NavigationEnd,
NavigationCancel,
NavigationError
Scroll
```

Here are all the navigation events you can look at the angular docs https://angular.io/api/router/Event

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but could you please point me to a resource where i can see more on this syntax? its unfamiliar to me and i cant seem to find any good explanation on it.

Comment: Please have look at this link https://angular.io/api/router/Event

Answer (score 0):

You should use NavigationEnd method from the angular routing lifecycle like this:-

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

     constructor(private router: Router) {}

       ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
          if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
             **// CALL  YOUR  FUNCTION HERE**
          }
        })
      }
```

For more reference please visit [angular navigation cycle demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-event)

Comment: Glad to hear that